# Как cделать автозапуск PowerShell скрипта при запуске ярлыка или exe

Tags: windows, powershell

Пробывал создать Bat, но он не запускает скрипт , а просто его открывает в текстовой форме.в Task Scheduler тоже нету Возможномти такой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оказывается я просто не верно запускал скрипт в батче, через cd start . А нужно:

```
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File *path*
```

Comment: Молодец, что разобрался!